# Spring Security 5 OAuth2 Client does work with AuthorizationServer based on legacy Spring Seucrity OAuth

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Currently Spring Security 5.0.x only includes new OAuth2 client, OAuth authorization server and resource server are planned in the further release.

I tried to use the legacy Spring Security OAuth 2.3 to provide authorization server.

I found there is an existed project here for this purpose.

https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-security-5-oauth-client

But I tried to upgrade `auth-service` to Spring boot 2.0, and use the latest `spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure` to handle auto configuration in Spring Boot 2.0.

When I ran these two applications in my local system, and got the error like the following when it return the client application.

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: [authorization_request_not_found]
Login with OAuth 2.0
Login Client
```

I have already forked this project and committed my changes to:

https://github.com/hantsy/spring-security-5-oauth-client

And also opened an issue on the issues of the upstream project.

https://github.com/spring-tips/spring-security-5-oauth-client/issues/5

**Update**: After I researched the https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js, the cookie will be problematic if the auth server and client(sso) used the same host and context path. I added **/uaa** as context path in auth server, it worked.